# How to use SWIG Generated C structures in Java as input to C functions via SWIG/JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

I have a SWIG interface file that exposes some C functions (via JNI) to my Java application and these C structures are used as input into the C function (via SWIG/JNI).  SWIG generates the structure as a Java class, but I'm unsure how to set the structures properties as the setters take a SWIG generated type.  I need to set the structures properties before passing it as input into the C function from my Java class.  example_location_id_t_ is the class I need to pass, but the setters for `Id` and `Phy_idx` take the below SWIG types. How do I populate the `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char` and `SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t` so that I can set the `Id` and `Phy_idx` properties of the `SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t` class?

`setId(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char value)` and `setPhy_idx(SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t value)`

```
package com.test.jni;

public class SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char {
  private long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char(long cPtr, boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}


package com.test.jni;

public class SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t {
  private long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t(long cPtr, boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}

package com.test.jni;

public class example_location_id_t_ {
  private long swigCPtr;
  protected boolean swigCMemOwn;

  public example_location_id_t_ (long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    swigCMemOwn = cMemoryOwn;
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  public static long getCPtr(example_location_id_t_ obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        ExampleJNI.delete_example_location_id_t_(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
  }

  public void setId(SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char value) {
      ExampleJNI.example_location_id_t__id_set(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char.getCPtr(value));
  }

  public SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char getId() {
    long cPtr = ExampleJNI.example_location_id_t__id_get(swigCPtr, this);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_char(cPtr, false);
  }

  public void setPhy_idx(SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t value) {
    ExampleJNI.example_location_id_t__phy_idx_set(swigCPtr, this, SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t.getCPtr(value));
  }

  public SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t getPhy_idx() {
    return new SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t(ExampleJNI.example_location_id_t__phy_idx_get(swigCPtr, this), true);
  }

  public example_location_id_t_() {
    this(ExampleJNI.new_example_location_id_t_(), true);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without being given any extra information SWIG defaults to assuming you want things wrapped as a type that can be returned and passed from one function to another, even if it can't be wrapped meaningfully in the target language.

Every time you see a type that begins `SWIGTYPE_...` it means SWIG didn't know how to generate a better wrapper and this was the best it managed to come up with.

SWIG does provide default typemaps that can help you here though:

- For `setPhy_idx(uint32_t value);` all you need to add in your interface is:

  ```
  %include "stdint.i"

  void setPhy_idx(uint32_t value);
  ```

  and a type which can represent a `uint32_t` will be used in the target language.
- For `setId(unsigned char *value);` it depends quite what `value` actually is - if it's a `NULL` terminated string you can do something like:

  ```
  %apply char * { unsigned char * };

  void setId(unsigned char *value);
  ```

  and a `String` will be used in your target language.

  If you wanted to pass the pointer as an integer type you could use something like:

  ```
  %apply unsigned long { unsigned char * };

  void setId(unsigned char *value);
  ```

  instead.

  If `unsigned char *value` is a pointer to a single `unsigned char` you could do:

  ```
  %include "typemaps.i"
  %apply unsigned char *INPUT { unsigned char *value };

  void setId(unsigned char *value);
  ```

  which instructs SWIG to treat the poitner as a single pointer. (This could be applied for the `uint32_t` if  it was a pointer too)

Comment: Hi awoodland, the example you provided worked perfectly for the phy_idx, but I later found out that the Id is a 32 byte char array on the C side. Its defined in the header file as typedef unsigned char example_id_v1_t[32]; Is there an include or apply that would create a useable Java strucutre?

Comment: @c12 - I think `%include "arrays_java.i"` would cover `unsigned char[32]` -> `short[]` for Java. (It has to be a `short`, because it's unsigned and wouldn't fit in `byte`). If it doesn't work let me know and I'll take another look at it.

Comment: the above two examples were great but what about for a function that takes a (void* input) as input?  If I want to pass a String from Java to the function what type of SWIG interface addition is needed?

Comment: or is it best to push to have a new C function created that takes a specific type?

Comment: if you want to pass a string (i.e. `char *`) for your `void *` you can use `%apply` to apply the rules for `char*` to the particular parameters - something like `%apply char * { void* input }`

Comment: @Flexo comment about %include "arrays_java.i" worked fine for me to pass  a c++ byte array giving a java short[]. Thanks