# SWIGTPYE_p data types Java

Tags: java, c++, types, type-conversion, swig

In the process of wrapping a native library in C++ to Java, I've come across the SWIGTYPE_p_ classes. Reading around the SWIG docs, and following the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235313/how-to-use-swig-generated-c-structures-in-java-as-input-to-c-functions-via-swig) I more or less understand that SWIG generates these classes when it doesn't know what to do with a C++ data type. It tries to create a pointer to the data type, but these SWIGTYPE classes seem to be functionally useless.

I have put `%include typemaps.i` in the .i file, and used typemaps for pointers like:

```
%apply char * {unsigned char *};
%apply float * {float *};
%apply int * {int *};
%apply int * {unsigned long *};
%apply short * {unsigned short *};
%apply byte * {byte *};
%apply long * {unsigned long long *};
```

I also tried using float[] { float[] }.

An example of where it goes wrong:

```
typedef union CAN_PKT_ {
   unsigned long long   all;
   float                f[2];
   unsigned long        ul[2];
   unsigned short       us[4];
   unsigned char        uc[8];
} CAN_PKT;
```

results in a class CAN_PKT with methods set_all, set_f etc, but set_f accepts SWIGTYPE_p_float as input, and SWITYPE_p_float has no contents other than the swigCptr and swigCMemOwn.

I guess I haven't typemapped float[] properly, but I don't really understand how it should be done and why?

**EDIT:** This union is the only place where the `short` data type is used. I can show this by running swig with this file left out of the .i file, SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_short isn't created. BUT if I comment out the contents of the union so that `unsigned short` is not used anywhere at all, and include this file into swig, it still creates SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_short. Why could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

SWIG has wrapped your array types as though they're a pointer - it can't expose the concept of a pointer in a higher level language very meaningfully though so it's being wrapped as an opaque type.

If you want to work with arrays then you can use [SWIG's support for arrays with Java](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#c_arrays) by doing:

```
%module test

%include "arrays_java.i"

typedef union CAN_PKT_ {
   unsigned long long   all;
   float                f[2];
   unsigned long        ul[2];
   unsigned short       us[4];
   unsigned char        uc[8];
} CAN_PKT;
```

Which generates the code you were hoping for. (This works compared to some of the other methods for wrapping arrays because the size of the array is fixed at compile time)